# Manage six mutually-exclusive audio players

Tags: javascript

I created this Javascript function to manage six simple audio players within a page, so that when one of them is put into play, it shows the pause button, and any other player that was playing previously, shows the play button.

Sometimes the play / pause mechanism gets stuck (although I don't know if it depends on too many statements).

And also JS Fiddle reports "this function has too many statements (78)".  Would there be a way to reduce the statements?

```
        window.onload = function() {

      // PLAY 1

      var myAudio = document.getElementById('my-audio');
      var suona = document.getElementById('suona');
      var pause = document.getElementById('pause');
      var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
      var progress = document.getElementById('progress');

      function displayControls() {
        suona.style.display = "block";
      }

      // check that the media is ready before displaying the controls
      if (myAudio.paused) {
        displayControls();
      } else {
        // not ready yet - wait for canplay event
        myAudio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
          displayControls();
        });
      }

      suona.addEventListener('click', function() {
        myAudio.play();
        suona.style.display = "none";
        pause.style.display = "block";

        pause2.style.display = "none";
        suona2.style.display = "block";
        pause3.style.display = "none";
        suona3.style.display = "block";
        pause4.style.display = "none";
        suona4.style.display = "block";
        pause5.style.display = "none";
        suona5.style.display = "block";
        pause6.style.display = "none";
        suona6.style.display = "block";
      });

      pause.addEventListener('click', function() {
        myAudio.pause();
        pause.style.display = "none";
        suona.style.display = "block";
      });

      // display progress

      myAudio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        //sets the percentage
        bar.style.width = parseInt(((myAudio.currentTime / myAudio.duration) * 100), 10) + "%";
      });

      progress.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        // calculate the normalized position clicked
        var clickPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / this.offsetWidth;
        var clickTime = clickPosition * myAudio.duration;

        // move the playhead to the correct position
        myAudio.currentTime = clickTime;
        myBufferedTimeRanges = myAudio.buffered;
        mySeekableTimeRanges = myAudio.seekable;
      });

      // PLAY 2

      var myAudio2 = document.getElementById('my-audio2');
      var suona2 = document.getElementById('suona2');
      var pause2 = document.getElementById('pause2');
      var bar2 = document.getElementById('bar2');
      var progress2 = document.getElementById('progress2');


      function displayControls2() {
        suona2.style.display = "block";
      }

      // check that the media is ready before displaying the controls
      if (myAudio2.paused) {
        displayControls2();
      } else {
        // not ready yet - wait for canplay event
        myAudio2.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
          displayControls2();
        });
      }

      suona2.addEventListener('click', function() {
        myAudio2.play();
        suona2.style.display = "none";
        pause2.style.display = "block";

        pause.style.display = "none";
        suona.style.display = "block";
        pause3.style.display = "none";
        suona3.style.display = "block";
        pause4.style.display = "none";
        suona4.style.display = "block";
        pause5.style.display = "none";
        suona5.style.display = "block";
        pause6.style.display = "none";
        suona6.style.display = "block";
      });

      pause2.addEventListener('click', function() {
        myAudio2.pause();
        pause2.style.display = "none";
        suona2.style.display = "block";
      });

      // display progress

      myAudio2.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        //sets the percentage
        bar2.style.width = parseInt(((myAudio2.currentTime / myAudio2.duration) * 100), 10) + "%";
      });

      progress2.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        // calculate the normalized position clicked
        var clickPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / this.offsetWidth;
        var clickTime = clickPosition * myAudio2.duration;

        // move the playhead to the correct position
        myAudio2.currentTime = clickTime;
        myBufferedTimeRanges = myAudio2.buffered;
        mySeekableTimeRanges = myAudio2.seekable;
      });

      // PLAY 3

      var myAudio3 = document.getElementById('my-audio3');
      var suona3 = document.getElementById('suona3');
      var pause3 = document.getElementById('pause3');
      var bar3 = document.getElementById('bar3');
      var progress3 = document.getElementById('progress3');

      function displayControls3() {
        suona3.style.display = "block";
      }

      // check that the media is ready before displaying the controls
      if (myAudio3.paused) {
        displayControls3();
      } else {
        // not ready yet - wait for canplay event
        myAudio3.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
          displayControls3();
        });
      }

      suona3.addEventListener('click', function() {
        myAudio3.play();
        suona3.style.display = "none";
        pause3.style.display = "block";

        pause.style.display = "none";
        suona.style.display = "block";
        pause2.style.display = "none";
        suona2.style.display = "block";
        pause4.style.display = "none";
        suona4.style.display = "block";
        pause5.style.display = "none";
        suona5.style.display = "block";
        pause6.style.display = "none";
        suona6.style.display = "block";
      });

      pause3.addEventListener('click', function() {
        myAudio3.pause();
        pause3.style.display = "none";
        suona3.style.display = "block";
      });

      // display progress

      myAudio3.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        //sets the percentage
        bar3.style.width = parseInt(((myAudio3.currentTime / myAudio3.duration) * 100), 10) + "%";
      });

      progress3.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        // calculate the normalized position clicked
        var clickPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / this.offsetWidth;
        var clickTime = clickPosition * myAudio3.duration;

        // move the playhead to the correct position
        myAudio3.currentTime = clickTime;
        myBufferedTimeRanges = myAudio3.buffered;
        mySeekableTimeRanges = myAudio3.seekable;
      });

      // PLAY 4

      var myAudio4 = document.getElementById('my-audio4');
      var suona4 = document.getElementById('suona4');
      var pause4 = document.getElementById('pause4');
      var bar4 = document.getElementById('bar4');
      var progress4 = document.getElementById('progress4');

      function displayControls4() {
        suona4.style.display = "block";
      }

      // check that the media is ready before displaying the controls
      if (myAudio4.paused) {
        displayControls4();
      } else {
        // not ready yet - wait for canplay event
        myAudio4.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
          displayControls4();
        });
      }

      suona4.addEventListener('click', function() {
        myAudio4.play();
        suona4.style.display = "none";
        pause4.style.display = "block";

        pause.style.display = "none";
        suona.style.display = "block";
        pause2.style.display = "none";
        suona2.style.display = "block";
        pause3.style.display = "none";
        suona3.style.display = "block";
        pause5.style.display = "none";
        suona5.style.display = "block";
        pause6.style.display = "none";
        suona6.style.display = "block";
      });

      pause4.addEventListener('click', function() {
        myAudio4.pause();
        pause4.style.display = "none";
        suona4.style.display = "block";
      });

      // display progress

      myAudio4.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        //sets the percentage
        bar4.style.width = parseInt(((myAudio4.currentTime / myAudio4.duration) * 100), 10) + "%";
      });

      progress4.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        // calculate the normalized position clicked
        var clickPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / this.offsetWidth;
        var clickTime = clickPosition * myAudio4.duration;

        // move the playhead to the correct position
        myAudio4.currentTime = clickTime;
        myBufferedTimeRanges = myAudio4.buffered;
        mySeekableTimeRanges = myAudio4.seekable;
      });

      // PLAY 5

      var myAudio5 = document.getElementById('my-audio5');
      var suona5 = document.getElementById('suona5');
      var pause5 = document.getElementById('pause5');
      var bar5 = document.getElementById('bar5');
      var progress5 = document.getElementById('progress5');


      function displayControls5() {
        suona5.style.display = "block";
      }

      // check that the media is ready before displaying the controls
      if (myAudio5.paused) {
        displayControls5();
      } else {
        // not ready yet - wait for canplay event
        myAudio5.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
          displayControls5();
        });
      }

      suona5.addEventListener('click', function() {
        myAudio5.play();
        suona5.style.display = "none";
        pause5.style.display = "block";

        pause.style.display = "none";
        suona.style.display = "block";
        pause2.style.display = "none";
        suona2.style.display = "block";
        pause3.style.display = "none";
        suona3.style.display = "block";
        pause4.style.display = "none";
        suona4.style.display = "block";
        pause6.style.display = "none";
        suona6.style.display = "block";
      });

      pause5.addEventListener('click', function() {
        myAudio5.pause();
        pause5.style.display = "none";
        suona5.style.display = "block";
      });

      // display progress

      myAudio5.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        //sets the percentage
        bar5.style.width = parseInt(((myAudio5.currentTime / myAudio5.duration) * 100), 10) + "%";
      });

      progress5.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        // calculate the normalized position clicked
        var clickPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / this.offsetWidth;
        var clickTime = clickPosition * myAudio5.duration;

        // move the playhead to the correct position
        myAudio5.currentTime = clickTime;
        myBufferedTimeRanges = myAudio5.buffered;
        mySeekableTimeRanges = myAudio5.seekable;
      });

      // PLAY 6

      var myAudio6 = document.getElementById('my-audio6');
      var suona6 = document.getElementById('suona6');
      var pause6 = document.getElementById('pause6');
      var bar6 = document.getElementById('bar6');
      var progress6 = document.getElementById('progress6');


      function displayControls6() {
        suona6.style.display = "block";
      }

      // check that the media is ready before displaying the controls
      if (myAudio6.paused) {
        displayControls6();
      } else {
        // not ready yet - wait for canplay event
        myAudio6.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
          displayControls6();
        });
      }

      suona6.addEventListener('click', function() {
        myAudio6.play();
        suona6.style.display = "none";
        pause6.style.display = "block";

        pause.style.display = "none";
        suona.style.display = "block";
        pause2.style.display = "none";
        suona2.style.display = "block";
        pause3.style.display = "none";
        suona3.style.display = "block";
        pause4.style.display = "none";
        suona4.style.display = "block";
        pause5.style.display = "none";
        suona5.style.display = "block";
      });

      pause6.addEventListener('click', function() {
        myAudio6.pause();
        pause6.style.display = "none";
        suona6.style.display = "block";
      });

      // display progress

      myAudio6.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        //sets the percentage
        bar6.style.width = parseInt(((myAudio6.currentTime / myAudio6.duration) * 100), 10) + "%";
      });

      progress6.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        // calculate the normalized position clicked
        var clickPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / this.offsetWidth;
        var clickTime = clickPosition * myAudio6.duration;

        // move the playhead to the correct position
        myAudio6.currentTime = clickTime;
        myBufferedTimeRanges = myAudio6.buffered;
        mySeekableTimeRanges = myAudio6.seekable;
      });

      //CLOSE

    }
```

Comment: "too many lines" is an opinion that the particular function/code block may be harder to read and/or understand due to its length. This "opinion" is a configuration value set in the "linter" (code analyzer) used in JSFiddle. It does not say "I detected a bug but I'm going to run it anyway. Good luck!"

Comment: *Sometimes the play / pause mechanism gets stuck*  => Code Review posts require working code.  See "Help" link in the lower right of this page.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Answer (score 1):

> And also JS Fiddle reports "this function has too many statements (78)". Would there be a way to reduce the statements?

- See [my comment about "too many lines"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/274307/manage-six-mutually-exclusive-audio-players#comment541758_274307)
- The code with:  *// check that the media is ready before displaying the controls*

  - Looks smelly to me. Adding eventListeners in a condition? Doesn't make sense. And it's executed immediately because it is not in a method/function.
  - event handlers are setting each others' properties. I'd bet this, along with the bullet above, is a big reason the app "gets stuck."
- WARNING! Given that confusion, don't assume I've reorganized style setting code completely correctly. A AudioPlayers collection event handler may very well set all of that.

Instantiate AudioPlayer objects. This will reduce total code ~ 80%. This structure will facilitate cleaning away that "loose code" and coordinate the control display and hide settings

```javascript
function AudioPlayer (audio, suona, pause, bar, progress) {

  this.myAudio  = document.getElementById(audio);
  this.suona    = document.getElementById(suona);
  this.pause    = document.getElementById(pause);
  this.bar      = document.getElementById(bar);
  this.progress = document.getElementById(progress);
  
  // for unique reference in a collection of AudioPlayers
  this.id = audio;
  
  this.addListeners();
  this.displayControls();
  
} // Player
```

---

Turn the methods into instance methods. This code block *is not inside* the
`AudioPlayer` object.

```javascript
AudioPlayer.prototype.displayControls() {
   // code here
}

AudioPlayer.prototype.hideControls() {
   // do your thing
}

// register all object event handlers in this method, just
// for convenience.
// DO NOT SET OTHER CONTROL'S VALUES. Do that in the collection object

AudioPlayer.prototype.addListeners() {
  this.myAudio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(event) {
    //sets the percentage
    event.target.bar.style.width = parseInt(((this.myAudio.currentTime / myAudio3.duration) * 100), 10) + "%";
  });
      
  this.suona.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.target.myAudio.play();
  });
  
  this.progress.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // calculate the normalized position clicked
     var clickPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / this.offsetWidth;
     var clickTime = clickPosition * this.myAudio.duration;
 
  // move the playhead to the correct position
     this.myAudio.currentTime = clickTime;
     myBufferedTimeRanges = this.myAudio.buffered;
     mySeekableTimeRanges = this.myAudio.seekable;
  });

  myAudio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
     displayControls();
  });


} // addEventListeners
```

Create a collection for easy control setting coordination.

- I suspect an event handler in this `AutoPlayers` collection can, in a simple loop, hide or unhide all the controls based on the `event.target`
- Remove all the code setting other controls' properties from all event handlers above. You'll set them in `AudioPlayers` event handler.

.

```javascript
// AudioPlayer collection for coordinating event behaviour
function AudioPlayers () {
  this.players = []
  
  this.add = function (newPlayer) {
    if(newPlayer) {
      players[newPlayer.id] = newPlayer;
    }
  }

  // event handler pseudo-code

   this.clickHandler = function (event) {
       this.players.each(player => 
           if (player.id == event.target.id) {
              player.displayControls();
           } else {
              player.hideControls();
           }
    } // clickHandler

} // AudioPlayers
```

---

Instantiate all the objects

```javascript
var audioPlayers = new AudioPlayers();
audioPlayers.Add (new AudioPlayer('my-audio', 'suona', 'pause', 'bar', 'progress' ));
audioPlayers.Add (new AudioPlayer('my-audio2', 'suona2', 'pause2', 'bar2', 'progress2' ));
audioPlayers.Add (new AudioPlayer('my-audio3', 'suona3', 'pause3', 'bar3', 'progress3' ));
audioPlayers.Add (new AudioPlayer('my-audio4', 'suona4', 'pause4', 'bar4', 'progress4' ));
audioPlayers.Add (new AudioPlayer('my-audio5', 'suona5', 'pause5', 'bar5', 'progress5' ));
audioPlayers.Add (new AudioPlayer('my-audio6', 'suona6', 'pause6', 'bar6', 'progress6' ));
```